# Class cast exception while running the jsp file

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to run one of my .jsp file and i'm getting class cast exception.

('org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager')

I have placed all my jars in WEB-INF/lib folder and I have included all the required jars.

Is this error occurs because of .jar versions mismatch?

Kindly let me know if anyone knows about this error.

Comment: Tell us which jars you put in WEB-INF/lib, and show us the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I have used these jars. annotations-api.jar, ecj-3.7.2.jar, el-api.jar, jasper-el.jar, jasper.jar, jsp-api.jar, servlet-api.jar, tomcat-api.jar, tomcat-coyote.jar, tomcat-dbcp.jar, tomcat-i18n-es.jar, tomcat-i18n-fr.jar, tomcat-i18n-ja.jar, tomcat-jdbc.jar, tomcat-util.jar

Comment: Please find the complete log. java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(InstanceManagerFactory.java:32)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not put tomcat's jar files into WEB-INF/lib. Tomcat already has thoses classes, and they must be loaded by the root tomcat classloader, not by the webapp's classloader. Unless there is a specific library in this list of jars that is not part of Tomcat, all those jars shouldn't be there.

What you put in WEB-INF/lib are libraries that your code uses, like Guava or OpenCSV or whatever jar you could have created yourself. Not Tomcat's own libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JB. So you want me to remove the tomcat related jars from the lib folder and include the jars using java build path in eclipse?

Comment: yes it works fine now! JB, Please correct me if i'm wrong. So when i'm deploying the J2EE application the jars related to tomcat should not be placed in lib folder. It will be picked by tomcat's root class loader automatically. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. But you shouldn't rely on anything tomcat-specific in your code. Except servlet-api.jar and maybe annotations-api.jar and el-api.jar, none of these jars should be in your classpath. Only add what you actually use.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You're deploying into Tomcat, and tomcat has its own jars. You don't provide an entire windows/linux OS libraries when you create a windows/linux app, do you? Same here. Tomcat is the OS of your webapp, if you will.

Comment: Hi Guys, 
I have got the same problem with my application. I haven't got any of the above libraries in my web-inf/lib folder. can you think of any other reason why I would get this problem? or do you have a list of libraries that I should check in my web-inf/lib ? Thanks